# Как сделать выбор всех элементов определённого цвета?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать выбор всех элементов определённого цвета?

Нужно искать по значению.

Хотелось бы что бы это было сделано с помощью селектора, типа такого:

```
.children("li").children("a:not(.act))"
```

На странице есть 4 атрибута `a`, в каждом написано слово "test". В двух из них, цвет текста синий, а в других двух, белый.  Нужно выбрать все элементы `a` с синем цветом.

```
//Цвет текста синий
<a href="#" class="ar">Test</a>
<a href="#" class="ar">Test</a>

//Цвет текста белый
<a href="#" class="ar">Test</a>
<a href="#" class="ar">Test</a>
```

Нужно выбрать все элементы с текстом синего цвета.

Comment: как вы задаете цвет?

Comment: @Grundy через css, color

Comment: классом или прямо в html-коде?

Comment: Приведите разметку html и результат который вы хотите получить

Comment: @Grundy Сделал. Но нужно найти именно не по классу а по свойству.

Comment: вам нужно только свойство `color`?

Comment: @Grundy выбрать по значению , только свойства color

Comment: Мне вот любопытно: зачем это понадобилось? Если и правда сильно нужно - перебирайте все элементы и проверяйте значения `element.getComputedStyle().color`(или `element.currentStyle.color` - для убогих браузеров) - что мешает? Или элементов очень много?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery позволяет расширять набор селекторов, которые можно использовать. Для этого используется следующий синтаксис

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'],{
    selectorName : function () { ... return true //если элемент удовлетворяет селектору }
});
```

Далее этот селектор можно использовать так:

```
$(':selectroName')
```

Таким образом можно добавить свой селектор, например `:rgb`.

Пример:

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
  rgb: function(el, index, param){
    console.log(el, param,$(el).css('color') , 'rgb('+param[3]+')');
    return $(el).css('color') == 'rgb('+param[3]+')';
  }
})

$('a:rgb(20, 20, 20)').css('border','1px solid green');
$('a:rgb(40, 40, 40)').css('border','1px solid red');
$('a:rgb(30, 30, 30)').css('border','1px solid blue');
```

```css
a:nth-of-type(1) {
 color: rgb(30,30,30);
}
.a,.b{
 color: rgb(40,40,40);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="a">Test</a>
<a class="a">Test</a>
<a class="b">Test</a>
<a style="color:rgb(20,20,20)">Test</a>
<a>Test</a>
```

Comment: Похоже вы тут один профессионал. Может обратите внимание на этот вопрос? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497451/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E

Comment: @Grundy а есть гарантия что css('color')  будет исключительно формата rgb?

Comment: @рони, вообще говоря, не уверен, зависит от реализации функции [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) в браузере, потому что в итоге все работает через нее

Comment: @Grundy немного дополнил ваш вариант

Answer (score 3):

**Дополнено**
В коде классы, добавляющие цвет. Но необходимо выбрать элементы по css-цвету, делаем так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>titile</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
  .black {
   color: black;
  }
  .green {
   color: green;
  }
 </style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){
   var d = $('div').map(function(index, el) {
    if ($(this).css('color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
     return this;
    }
   });
   console.log(d);
   d.css('border', '2px solid tomato');
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="black">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
<div class="green">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
<div class="black">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
<div class="green">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Ну например так:
`$('.yellow').children().not('.red').css('border', '2px solid green')`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>titile</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>

 </style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){
   $('.yellow').children().not('.red').css('border', '2px solid green')
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="yellow">
 <div class="red">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
 <div class="green">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
 <div class="red">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
 <div class="green">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
 <div class="red">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Или так
`$('.yellow').children(':not(.green)').css('border', '2px solid red')`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>titile</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>

 </style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){
   $('.yellow').children(':not(.green)').css('border', '2px solid red')
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="yellow">
 <div class="red">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
 <div class="green">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
 <div class="red">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
 <div class="green">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
 <div class="red">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Или вообще проще всего просто селектором
`$('.yellow').children('.red').css('border', '2px solid green')`

Comment: Ну вы находите по классу а не по свойству css. То есть, нужно найти по свойству, все объекты тега - `a` с черным цветом

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, так вы сами писали, что задаете значение классом... Вы уж определитесь

Comment: @Jean-Claude Верно, задаётся значение классом, но искать нужно по значению, не по классу.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов приведите пример. Пока неясно, чего вы хотите

Comment: @Jean-Claude На странице есть 4 атрибута `a`, в каждом написано слово "test". В двух из них, цвет текста синий, а в других двух, белый.  Нужно выбрать все элементы `a` с синем цветом.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов дополнил

Comment: @Jean-Claude Да, но хотелось бы типо того : `.children("li").children("a:not(.act))` Тут запись происходит не в массив.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, лучше `filter` использовать чем `map`

Comment: @Grundy поясните.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов типо того я вам все примеры дал. `children("a:not(.act))` - act тут у вас имя класса, в моих примерах есть.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, для фильтрации коллекции элементов предназначен метод `filter`, вы же делает фильтрацию через метод `map` - возвращаете элемент когда подходит и ничего не возвращаете когда нет

Comment: @Jean-Claude Похоже что правильно делать через filter

Comment: @Grundy оки, в следующий раз использовать его.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов хватить ныть, это одно и то же, задача решена. С помощью приведенных примеров вполне можно подставить filter, вместо map, за вас никто писать не будет.

Comment: @Jean-Claude ты возвращаешь массив. А тут возвращается не массив - children("a:not(.act)) - это для примера Не зацыкливайся. А еще она устаревшая

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов не массив, а объект jquery, обладающий его методами и свойствами, точно такой же как и в случае выборки children.

Comment: @Jean-Claude коллекция элементов , называется.  Но он возвращает массив. Но он устаревший. Перепиши все и используй фильтр и я поставлю галочку

Comment: @Jean-Claude вот задачка полегче http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497451/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E

Answer (score 3):

дополненный вариант Grundy если цвет указан в ином формате, например color: red;

```js
 jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
   color: function(el, index, param) {
     var color = $("<" + el.tagName + ">").css('color', param[3]).css('color');
     return $(el).css('color') == color;
   }
 })
 $('a:color(rgb(20, 20, 20))').css('border', '1px solid green');
 $('a:color(red)').css('border', '1px solid red'); //test
 $('a:color(rgb(40, 40, 40))').css('border', '1px solid blue');
```

```css
a:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: red;
}
.a,
.b {
  color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="a">Test color: red</a>
<a class="a">Test</a>
<a class="b">Test</a>
<a style="color:rgb(20,20,20)">Test</a>
<a>Test</a>
```