# Как добавить коллекцию элементов в переменную

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как добавить коллекцию элементов в переменную?

Нужно добавить, каждый второй элемент

Пример что нужно:

```
var  $item_v = $(".aе");
var  $item_b;


  for(var i_nav4 = 0; i_nav4 < 4 ; i_nav4++){ 
     //тут мы должны добавлять элементы коллекции объекта $item_v в $item_b

       if(i_nav4 === 1 || i_nav4 === 3 ){
         находим элемент-------->$item_v.eq(i_nav4)
         $item_b <--- добавляем сюда найденный элемент
        }
    }
```

Comment: [jquery.clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/). а после редактирования [jquery.filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/). А также у вас синтаксическая ошибка здесь _$(.aе)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
   var $item_v = $(".ae");
   var $item_b;
   for (var i_nav4 = 0; i_nav4 < 4; i_nav4++) {

     if (i_nav4 === 1 || i_nav4 === 3) {

       $item_b = $item_b ? $item_b.add($item_v.eq(i_nav4)) : $item_v.eq(i_nav4)
     }
   }
   $item_b.css({
     "background-color": "#FF00FF"
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ae">0</span>
<span class="ae">1</span>
<span class="ae">2</span>
<span class="ae">3</span>
<span class="ae">4</span>
<span class="ae">5</span>
```

Comment: чтобы убрать тернарный оператор, можно присвоить `var $item_b = $();` Тогда внутри их достаточно просто вызвать метод `add` без каких либо присвоений. Ну и еще раз скажу, что было бы не плохо не только код в ответе, но и описание как именно решается проблема.

Comment: @Grundy ума не приложу что тут описывать

Answer (score 3):

Икебану его, вот вам фильтрация:

```js
$(function() {
  var d = $('div').filter(function(index, elem) {
    return (index % 2 != 0);
  }).clone();
  console.log(d);
  d.css('border', '2px solid tomato').appendTo('body');
});
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="black">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
<div class="green">2 lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
<div class="black">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
<div class="green">4 lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
<div class="black">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
<div class="green">6 lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
<br>Результат будет тут:
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Хорошо. Но есть А и B , нужно с A скопировать в B. Так как у меня в вопросе. И не важно для чего это и что это не правильно ит.д Это не важно как это будет использоваться. Ответ полезный, но не более.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов после меня код правили, видимо вместе, сейчас всё пучком.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то надо как-то так:

```
var $item_b = {}; 

for (var attr in $item_v) {
    if (item_b.hasOwnProperty(attr)) item_b[attr] = obj[attr];
}
```

Более подробно про копирование объектов читайте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Примерно так, посмотрите еще мой вопрос, я его обновил.